# Usage of openMP Shared clause in C++

Tags: c++, openmp

According to [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbcpx01/cuppvars.htm)

**All variables defined outside a parallel construct become shared when the parallel region is encountered.**

I am wondering what would be the usage of openMP **Shared** clause while developing in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if variables are shared by default, the default can be changed by the `default()` clause. When you have `default(none)` or `default(private)` you have to declare shared variables explicitly.

There many many uses for shared variables.

A large array is typically used `shared` and different threads are operating on a different part of the array.

Or a configuration parameter which you are only reading, not modifying, that can be shared.

Or a global variable defining some state or a flag even if you are changing that under some condition. You would have it shared and change it in a critical or single section.

Comment: Thanks. When  e.g. A large array is by default a shared variable (if it is declared before parallel region) what is the point of declaring it as a shared variable?

Comment: You would declare it explicitly to document it is shared. And when you use `default(none)` you have to declare all variables. And when you have `default(private)` you have to declare all shared variables.

Comment: I understand it. If I do not use default(none), is it still necessary to declare it as shared(largeArray)?